# When updating a Jframe designed, the automatic code generator sets insets to null in netbeans 7.0.1

Tags: java, netbeans-7

When updating a Jframe designed (GridBag), the automatic code generator sets insets to null in netbeans 7.0.1

My Error is

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.GridBagConstraints.clone(GridBagConstraints.java:652)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.setConstraints(GridBagLayout.java:499)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.addLayoutComponent(GridBagLayout.java:700)
    at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1120)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:966)
    at Audit.pnl7.initComponents(pnl7.java:633)
    at Audit.pnl7.<init>(pnl7.java:64)
...............
```

How to fix this issue.
Thanks

Comment: Try to post more code?

Comment: As @Abdelhak suggested, please share the code that might be causing the exception you pasted. This can help us to help you.